# MySqlException was unhandled error trying to create relational database

Tags: c#, mysql

I get this error when i am trying to create a relational database:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' REFERENCES classes(Name))' at line 1
```

I used a `Update` method to update the data base and create new tables, the first `Update` method works but then the second one breaks it. This is my code

```
one.Update("CREATE TABLE classes (Name VARCHAR (30) , Primitive1 VARCHAR(30), Primitive2 VARCHAR(30), Primitive3 VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY(Name)) ");           

one.Update("CREATE TABLE primitives (Name VARCHAR(30), Size_bytes INT, Description TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (Classes), REFERENCES classes(Name))" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have other problems, but you have an extra comma in the `foreign key` statement:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Classes), REFERENCES classes(Name)
```

should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Classes) REFERENCES classes(Name)
```

I note that you have no actual column called `Classes` in the table.  Either you need to declare that, or you might mean:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES classes(Name)
```

EDIT:

And I'm a strong advocate of auto incrementing keys:

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
    ClassesId int auto_increment primary key,
    Name VARCHAR(30) not null unique,
    Primitive1 VARCHAR(30),
    Primitive2 VARCHAR(30),
    Primitive3 VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE primitives(
    PrimitivesId int auto_increment primary key,
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    Size_bytes INT,
    Description TEXT,
    ClassId int references classes(ClassId)
);
```

Note the use of inline references.  I'm sure some will disagree, but I find it easier to follow column definitions when they are in one place.  Also, this adds auto-incrementing primary keys and uses the same column name for the primary key and foreign key.

Finally, having three columns that look the same -- `Primitive1`, `Primitive2`, and `Primitive3` -- is usually a poor design.  It is better to have another table with one row per class and "Primitive".

Answer (score 0):

```
    one.Update("CREATE TABLE primitives (Name VARCHAR(30), Size_bytes INT, Description TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (Classes) REFERENCES classes(Name))" );
```

is correct. You had comma `,` before `REFERENCES`